# Global context in velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I'd like to define global variables in velocity. I had a look at VelocityTools but I'm afraid the tools don't help. The ContextTool I found [here](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ContextTool.html) doesn't offer methos for putting data into the Context. Only methods for getting data from the context are available. Is this the wrong tool for getting AND putting data? Is there another tool for this purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is the correct tool for your purpose. You can access the context using the [`getThis()`](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ContextTool.html#getThis%28%29) method:

```
contextTool.getThis().put("variable", variable);
```

Comment: Or $context.this.put("variable", variable) if you are in a template.